# Using the Linux kernel in a commercial product

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, open-source, licensing

I've researched on the internet about GPL licensing and if it is possible to use the kernel in a commercial product, however, I always come across conflicting information.

Say I have an embedded system that that runs the kernel, and on top of that runs the embedded software that is written by me. Am I allowed to then sell the product to customers *without* then giving them the source code for the software *I have written*? For example, trade secrets, commercial viability, someone else then using my code to produce a similar product etc.

Comment: The answer is complicated as it depends on what type of GPL licensing, where your software runs (user/kernel), what it links to, etc.  This is not really the forum for this kind of question as it is not specifically about coding.  See http://stackexchange.com/sites for other forums (maybe Programmer would work?).

Comment: You shouldn't get legal advice from a random QnA site.

Comment: *"if it is possible to use the kernel in a commercial product"* -- Of course it's possible.  It has been done for years.  Go search for the "open-source code" sites of some consumer product manufacturers like LG and Samsung.

Comment: Ah yes I know its possible, I was asking if I have to make the source for my application open source too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and legal requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software runs on top of the kernel, then I suggest you read [the license](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/COPYING) of the kernel:

> NOTE! This copyright does *not* cover user programs that use kernel
>   services by normal system calls – this is merely considered normal use
>   of the kernel, and does *not* fall under the heading of "derived work".